# bibliography does not appear using a template which uses apalike style

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

When I compile the tex provided in the following template, the bibliography does not appear, and I don't understand why. I'm using Texmaker on windows, and I've already tried to compile with BibTex before PdfLatex, but the references does not appear:

http://www.scitepress.org/documents/SCITEPRESS_Conference_Latex.zip

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that you extracted all of the files from the zip and put them into the same directory. I uploaded and got a successful compile with the following.  Using Texmaker and the Tools menu. Run LaTeX (not pdfLaTeX) once, then Run Bibtex, Then Latex Twice.  And if you want a pdf not just dvi, run again from Tools dvi->pdf.   The example document has an interesting structure and I am assuming that the source of the example wants a *.dvi output.